# How do I recover word text from windows 7 - i was composing & I hit delete by accident - I am NOT tech savvy

Tags: windows-7, windows

I was writing a speech and I accidently hit delete and it isn't saved. Is there any way to recover 3 hours of work?

Comment: Did you try ctrl+z (`Edit` -> `Undo`)? Or did you delete the whole file?

Comment: I don't understand "accidentally hit delete" - if nothing was highlighted, pressing delete would only remove one character ahead of the cursor if any... To remove all text, you'd have to highlight the text first, then click delete, which seems hard to do accidentally. Clicking it on a file should produce a confirmation popup asking if you're sure to delete...

Answer (score 0):

You do not say what software you are using to write the document. We need to know more details.

Definitely try control-z (undo), you can do this multiple times. If this was just a few keystrokes away it should get you back.

If it was Microsoft Word 2013 (Office 365) then you could try looking in the File : Info : Versions. The auto-save may have saved a version before the delete.

Edit : Re-reading the question I think perhaps the document is in the recycle bin? Could this be all this is?

Answer (score 0):

If you remember the filename, or some CONTENT you might be lucky by using the File search in Explorer (Windows+E).

Direct your searches into the TEMPORARY file folders, e.g. type one of these into the explorer address/folder field (press F4, then type, then F3 to search):

%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\
%TEMP%
%TMP%